# Spring Data JPA - создать Entity с ссылкой на саму себя

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Подскажите, как, используя Spring Data JPA, создать Entity с ссылкой на саму себя, как правильно аннотировать поля класса если нужно получать как возможного родителя, так и детей?

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
public class Point {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @?
    private Point parent;

    @?
    private List<Point> children;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В создании отношений между сущностями очень помогает плагин [JPA Buddy](https://www.jpa-buddy.com/), особенно его функционал Reverse Engineering (в последней версии - платный)

Для начала создадим структуру дерева в базе (я использовал PostgreSQL, но для других реляционных БД изменения будут не кардинальными):

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.tree (
    id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    parent_id int4 NULL, -- ссылка на родителя
    "data" varchar NOT NULL, -- и что-то из полезной нагрузки
    CONSTRAINT tree_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT tree_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES public.tree(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- и наполним данными
INSERT INTO public.tree (parent_id, "data")
VALUES 
  (NULL, 'root'),
  (1, 'child1'), -- исключительно для примера, считая что таблицу только создали
  (1, 'child2'), -- и identity стартанёт с 1.
  (2, 'child1_1'),
  (2, 'child1_2');
```

теперь можно создать сущность, используя JPA Buddy->new entity from DB:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "tree")
public class TreeNode {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private TreeNode parentNode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentNode", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TreeNode> childNodes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "data", nullable = false)
    private String data;
}
// и репозиторий:
public interface TreeRepository extends JpaRepository<TreeNode, Integer> {
}
```

Собственно, на этом всё: если не забывать, что для полей используется FetchType.LAZY, то "прогуливаться" по дереву можно в обе стороны.

Пример, оформленный в виде юнит-теста:

```java
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
class TreeNodeRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private TreeRepository repository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void walkTopToBottom(){
        TreeNode root = repository.findById(1).orElseThrow(); // да, здесь жестко зашитые значения, основанные на SQL выше.
        log.info("root element data = " + root.getData());
        log.info("===========================");
        printTree(root);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void walkBottomToTop(){
        // достаём элемент самого низкого уровня
        TreeNode node = repository.findById(5).orElseThrow(); // да, здесь жестко зашитые значения, основанные на SQL выше.
        log.info("bottom element data = " + node.getData());
        log.info("===========================");

        TreeNode root = node;
        while (Objects.nonNull(root.getParentNode()))
            root = root.getParentNode(); // и поднимаемся вверх до корня


        printTree(root);
    }

    private void printTree(@NotNull TreeNode item){
        log.info("tree element = " + item.getData());
        if (Objects.nonNull(item.getChildNodes()))
            item.getChildNodes().forEach(this::printTree);
    }
}
```